# Finding the number of agents working for a manager in a certain week

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say you have a table that has `agent_id,manager_id,started_at,created_at,ended_at` fields and one wants to find the number of agents being managed by a certain manager in a certain week. How would you go about this in SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results.  Explain what *you* mean by "week".   I also removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: mysql or postgres? Please tag the question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Apologies, newbie to question asking in stackoverflow. I am using postgresql

Comment: @GordonLinoff by week I mean a standard week , Monday - Sunday or in postgresql EXTRACT(week from created_at), this will normally give you an integer

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *number of agents* means you want a count of the number of rows, i.e. `count(*)`
- *managed by a certain manager* means your query criteria needs to include `manager_id = <some_value>`
- *in a certain week* means your query criteria needs to include both `started_at` and `ended_at`

```
SELECT count(agent_id)  
FROM   table  
WHERE  manger_id = ?  
AND    started_at >= ?  
AND    ended_at <= ?
```

Replace the `?` in the above SQL with relevant values.